# Error during connection between pyspark and Elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

I have this code in Jupyter

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SQLContext
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import py4j


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Reader") \
    .master("local[2]") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

spark
```

It works well, the output is :

```
SparkSession - hive

SparkContext

Spark UI

Version
    v2.4.5
Master
    local[2]
AppName
    Reader
```

I would like to create a Reader from pyspark to Elasticsearch (based in localhost:9200), so I tried:

```
es_reader = (spark.read
    .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("es.read.field.as.array.include", "tags")
    .option("es.nodes","127.0.0.1:9200")
    .option("es.net.http.auth.user","elastic")
)
```

But when I try this

```
sysmon_df = (es_reader.load("winlogbeat"))
```

I have this error... Why?

```
>>---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ed6c79458d81> in <module>
----> 1 sysmon_df = (es_reader.load("winlogbeat"))

~/Scaricati/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    164         self.options(**options)
    165         if isinstance(path, basestring):
--> 166             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
    167         elif path is not None:
    168             if type(path) != list:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/Scaricati/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.elasticsearch.spark.sql. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:634)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying it doesn't know what to do about this

```
format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
```

Spark will not automatically download and set up your external dependencies!

Look up various examples and tutorials about including `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` with a `--packages` value

Comment: Thanks for answering me... so what do you suggest to do? I have already downloaded and installed spark-hadoop and imported it in the jupyter notebook... Should I have to use spark-submit shell?

Comment: 1) You don't need Hadoop. 2) Did you find any tutorials listing the variable I mentioned? And by the way, Spark still requires Java 8

Comment: Kinda... I found something about loading jar dependencies (so the jar required is spark.sql?). I've already Java

Comment: Spark includes `spark.sql` itself. It does not have `org.elasticsearch.*` packages to import via `os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] `

Comment: yeah I also tried                                                             `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars elasticsearch-hadoop-6.1.1/dist/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.1.1.jar pyspark-shell' `                            but nothing

Comment: That jar needs to be on every Spark worker. Try `--packages`  option instead without using a local jar file

Comment: using `--packages`  I have this error  `Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number` caused by ` --> 17     .master("local[2]") \` . Searching for this error on internet, I found it was caused by ` $JAVA_HOME ` in  `.bashrc ` ... But everything is ok

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the full exception? and updated code?

Comment: I can't write here the whole Exception... so I answered to my post. Please see below

Comment: I've never seen that exception before. Are you able to just run `pyspark` by itself? and run code in the terminal? Also, you will need Java 8 installed and a valid `JAVA_HOME` env var

Comment: yeah I have java 8 and the `$JAVA_HOME` in .bashrc ... Unfortunately I can't run the code in the terminal with pyspark

Comment: What happens when you try?